# Disable database switching in sitecore backend

Tags: content-editor, experience-editor, permissions

A customer of ours asked if it is possible to fix the account they are using in the sitecore backend (Experience Editor, Centent ediror, Media library, ...) to only the master database.
Our accounts should still be able to access the web, but theirs shouldn't

Comment: Remove read access to the database switcher maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17565265/661447

Comment: Do they also want to restrict who can _publish_ to web?

Comment: No, they must still be able to publish, just remove the possibility to switch (to avoid making changes in the wrong database)

Comment: Even if the switcher is removed, you could still alter the URL and gain access that way. You're going to need a custom request pipeline component after the database context is resolved to check security roles and enforce the rules. I reckon a profile switch ought to do the job, or a role group.

Answer (score 2):

Long shot.. can you try disabling access to below item in core db for the user role and verify if this solves your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the following steps to remove database switcher for particular account.

- Login to Sitecore.
- Go to the desktop. Select core database.
- Go back to Launchpad.
- Go to Security Editor.
- Select the appropriate account on top.
- In content tree, go to content->Applications->Desktop->Tray->Database
- Select Denied access (x) on read.

It will remove the database switcher for a particular account while it will show for other accounts.
Look at the screenshot below.

[image].